# PySpark remove duplicated messages within a 24h window after an initial new value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a status (integer) and a timestamp. Since I get a lot of "duplicated" status messages, I want to reduce the dataframe by removing any row which repeats a previous status within a 24h window after a "new" status, meaning:

- The first 24h window starts with the first message of a specific status.
- The next 24h window for that status starts with the next message that comes *after* that first 24h window (the windows are not back-to-back).

Given the example:

```
data = [(10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
        (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 04:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
        (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
        (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 05:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
        (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),

        (20, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 03:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      ]

myschema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("status", IntegerType()),
        StructField("ts", TimestampType())
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=myschema)
```

- The first 24h window for status `10` is from `2022-01-01 00:00:00` until `2022-01-02 00:00:00`.
- The second 24h window for status `10` is from `2022-01-02 05:00:00` until `2022-01-03 05:00:00`.
- The first 24h window for status `20` is from `2022-01-01 03:00:00` until `2022-01-02 03:00:00`.

As a result, I want to keep the messages:

```
data = [(10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
        (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 05:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),

        (20, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 03:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
      ]
```

I know how to do this in Python by looping and keeping track of the latest change and I think I need to use a Window function with partitionBy + orderBy, but I cannot figure out the details... any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean using `lag_window = Window.partitionBy('status').orderBy('unix_ts')`?

Comment: That's the question, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice question, i spent some time trying to fiugre it out. I have something like this:

```
At first i am calculating time diff in hours from prev element for each row within window
Then i am aggregating above values together as a new column for each row (first row has null, next [4], third [4,19] etc
Then i am using accumulator to calculate cumSum with your condition, so it "resets" after 24h
Then i am using this cumSum to assign "inner window"
Filtering at the end and i am done
```

Probably this is not the best way to do it so comments appreciated :D

Sample code:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 04:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 05:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-02 16:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-03 16:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (10, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-03 17:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
    (20, datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01 03:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
]

myschema = StructType(
    [StructField("status", IntegerType()), StructField("ts", TimestampType())]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=myschema)

window = Window.partitionBy("status").orderBy(["ts"])

df = df.withColumn(
        "timeDiffFromPrev",
        (((F.col("ts")).cast("long") - F.lag("ts").over(window).cast("long")) / 3600).cast("long"),
    )

df = df.withColumn('aggTimeDiffFromPrev', F.collect_list('timeDiffFromPrev').over(window))

#Zero aggregate when sum > 24h
expr = "AGGREGATE(aggTimeDiffFromPrev, 0l, (accumulator, element) -> IF(accumulator < 24, accumulator + element, element))"
df = df.select('status', 'ts', F.expr(expr).alias('cumsum'))

#Assign window number based on cumSum - anything greater than 24 is beggining of new window
df = df.withColumn(
        "window_number",
        F.sum(
            F.when((F.col("cumsum") > 24), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
        ).over(window),
    )

innerWindow = Window.partitionBy("status", "window_number").orderBy(["ts"])

#Keep only first row in window, drop other
df = df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(innerWindow)).filter(
    F.col("row_number") == F.lit(1)
).drop("timeDiffFromFirst", "window_number", "row_number", "cumSum")

df.show()
```

I added few line on the input just for tests, for my input dataset results are as follows:

```
+------+-------------------+
|status|                 ts|
+------+-------------------+
|    10|2022-01-01 00:00:00|
|    10|2022-01-02 05:00:00|
|    10|2022-01-03 16:00:00|
|    20|2022-01-01 03:00:00|
+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I am unable to test it right now, but will have a look into it first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: Thoroughly tested it, works perfectly. Very creative! The `collect_list` might become expensive, but right now "working" is what I am here for :D Thanks! Bounty awarded!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is challenging because the window function by default has a rolling behavior but you need the tumbling behavior i.e. once a partition is computed then ignore the rest of the elements in it and move to the next one.

So you can try the following approach using a udf.

```py
ndf = df.groupBy('status').agg(F.collect_list('ts'))
```

This will create a list of dates for similar Id's

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

def keep_24_hour_unique(in_row):
    # Sort the array in the row and perform the uniqueness logic here
    pass

magicUDF = udf(lambda z: keep_24_hour_unique(z), ArrayType(StringType)) 

ndf = df.withColumn('unique_dates', magicUDF)
```

The new dataframe will have results as an array. To convert those arrays into separate rows you can use pyspark `explode` function.

Comment: I'd rather hope to avoid using UDFs since leaving the PySpark world and de-/serializing is expensive as hell... I will keep it in mind though!

Comment: You are correct that udf costs for serialization but the solution with multiple windows and group by require a lot of data shuffling in spark so it might further decrease the performance. You can run tests and view spark execution plan to decide which solution is better for your use case.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
# Define a Window partitioned by status and ordered by timestamp
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("status").orderBy("ts")
   
# Calculate the difference between the current row timestamp and the previous row timestamp (in seconds)
time_diff = unix_timestamp(col("ts")) - unix_timestamp(lag(col("ts")).over(window_spec))

# Filter out rows with a time difference less than 24 hours (86400 seconds)
filtered_df = df.withColumn("time_diff", time_diff) \
    .filter((col("time_diff") >= 86400) | col("time_diff").isNull()) \
    .drop("time_diff")
```